# In the ruby method block, how can I get the variable name assigned to the method return value

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to do this?

As shown below:

```
def get_variables
  puts assigned_variables
end
```

one variable

```
a = get_variables
# => ['a']
```

multi variables

```
a, b = get_variables
# => ['a', 'b']
```

none

```
get_variables
# => []
```

PS:

hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

In JavaScript, We can use destructuring assignment syntax to destruct Objects.

```
const {a, b} = hash;
// a = 1, b = 2
```

Is there any way to do this in Ruby?
Even simpler than values_at.

```
a, b = hash.values_at :a, :b
```

Comment: As far as I know a Ruby method cannot reflect on if/how the return value is being used.

Comment: sounds like an XY problem. https://xyproblem.info/
Could you provide more context, why you need to do this?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous It's an XY problem. I add some context to clarify what I want.

Comment: @alex374 AFAIK there isn't, not for hashes. I guess you could get it done, but I don't know of any simple way for it

Comment: @alex374 you should put the actual problem first, i.e. the "destructure a hash like in JS" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In JavaScript, We can use destructuring assignment syntax to destruct Objects.
>
> Is there any way to do this in Ruby?

There was a [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8895) but it was rejected. Matz [suggested](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8895#note-17) that:

> *"this kind of problems should be addressed by pattern matching"*

[Ruby 2.7.](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/) then introduced experimental [pattern matching](https://speakerdeck.com/k_tsj/pattern-matching-new-feature-in-ruby-2-dot-7):

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

hash in {a:, b:}    # <- this is the experimental syntax
#=> true

a #=> 1
b #=> 2
```

Note that although the above currently works, it will print a warning:

```
One-line pattern matching is experimental, and the behavior may change in future versions of Ruby!
```

Comment: Worth noting, in ruby 3.1 this warning goes way even though the syntax hasn't changed. This means it is probably safe to use this syntax even if using an older version of ruby.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible say you have the same setup above no matter what you return from the method it will just assign accordingly

```
def get_variables
  [] || ['a', 'b'] || ['a']
end
```

some result that you would encounter are the following

1. For assignments

```
def get_variables
  []
end

a, b = get_variables
puts a
# => nil
puts b
# => nil
get_variables
# => []
# This is because you are expecting to receive the value inside the array and because the array is empty it will not assign anything to a or b.

# though if you have the method setup like this
def get_variables
  ['sample']
end
a, b = get_variables
puts a
# => sample
puts b
# => nil
get_variables
# => ['sample']
# In this case the system expected  that you are assinging values to multiple variables


# And lastly if you are assigning the method to only one variable the system will just expect that whatever you are returning will be assigned to the variable.
a = get_variables
puts a
# => ['sample']


# even when the method has this response
def get_variables
  []
end
a = get_variables
puts a
# => []

# the variable will be anything returned by the method.
```

Comment: I add some context to clarify what I want. See ps below.